# passing multiple arguments to a thread pool executor

Tags: python, executor

I am writing a code to run pool executor and use a function with two arguments.

```
    args=[(0,users[0]),(1,users[1]),(2,users[2]),(3,users[3]),(4,users[4]),(5,users[5]),(6,users[6])]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results=[executor.submit(do_all,(a,b)) for (a,b) in args]
        
            for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                print(result)`
```

I think the problem here is in the unpacking, but I couldn't do it with all trials

Please need support

I need to run it as expected

Comment: You need `executor.submit(do_all,a,b)` instead of `executor.submit(do_all,(a,b))`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi really thank you very much, it solved that issue

Answer (score 4):

You need `executor.submit(do_all,a,b)` instead of `executor.submit(do_all,(a,b))`, as stated by [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951132/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-thread-pool-executor#comment132266491_74951132).